# Ajax form submitting same information to database when it should be submitting new information

Tags: html, jquery, database, postgresql, forms

I have a form that has input groups in a  that the user fills out to add information to a table in my database. When they click the add button it submits the form without page reload and then creates a new blank table row to add more information if the user needs to. However, when I type in data to the new row that was generated on click and I hit the add button again to submit the new data, it ignores that data and instead submits the previous data again. I'm not sure how to set up the ajax call to get this working properly. Any advice is greatly appreciated!

This is the ajax call and the method to create a new table row when the button is clicked.

```
const cloneRow = $('#tableData tbody tr').first();

    $('#addRow').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let data = {
         project_id: $("#project_id").val(),
         imp_or_ann: $("#imp_or_ann").val(),
         category: $("#category").val(),
         cost: $("#cost").val(),
         hours: $("#hours").val()
    }
        $.ajax({
            url: '/costs_hours',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data
        }).then(
            cloneRow.clone().appendTo('#tableData tbody')
        )

    })
```

And this is my html page. I want to be able to add new data with the button at the bottom of the page, but it always submits the previous data rather than the new data that is inputted into the dynamically generated table row.

```
<form id="formData" action='/costs_hours' method="POST">
        <h1 class="text-center mb-3">Costs and Hours</h1>
        <div class="card border-secondary w-100 text-light" style="background-color: #333f48">

            <div class="card-body w-100 text-end">
                <table class="table text-light text-center mt-3">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Project ID</th>
                            <th scope="col">Implementation or Annual</th>
                            <th scope="col">Category</th>
                            <th scope="col">Costs</th>
                            <th scope="col">Hours</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                    <input id="project_id" name="project_id" type="text" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                        <select id="imp_or_ann" name="imp_or_ann" class="form-select"
                                            id="inputGroupSelect01">
                                            <option disabled selected>Choose...</option>
                                            <option>Implementation</option>
                                            <option>Annual</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                        <select id="category" name="category" class="form-select"
                                            id="inputGroupSelect01">
                                            <option disabled selected>Choose...</option>
                                            <option>EMO</option>
                                            <option>Analysts</option>
                                            <option>Maintenance</option>
                                            <option>ETS</option>
                                            <option>BOT</option>
                                            <option>OtherUT</option>
                                            <option>Materials</option>
                                            <option>Non-UT Contract</option>
                                            <option>Contingency</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                    <input id="cost" name="cost" type="text" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                    <input id="hours" name="hours" type="text" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <button id='addRow' type="button" style="background-color: #bf5700;"
                    class="btn btn-warning text-light">Add</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

This is an example of what the data looks like in the database. The second row should be different from the first because I had entered different data, but it just copies the same data instead of posting new data.

```
"Test"  "Implementation"    "EMO"   1   1   285
"Test"  "Implementation"    "EMO"   1   1   286
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have put an ID on the inputs. For the 1st entry, there is a single row so it works well. Then, your code clones the row (including the IDs). The code is still searching for data by ID, but now there are 2 sets of inputs with the same ID. A random one (the 1st one) is found.

Instead of using an ID, you can use a class and look for the last entry of the class to retrieve the values.

```
$(".project_id").last().val()
```